# Which PHP-template to load depends on javascript support

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following scenario:

A multiple step registration procedure. Let's say it's 4 steps, and each step depends on previous input. This could be solved with or without Javascript.

Without JS: A "proceed"-button is attached to each step
With JS: The next part is automatically revealed to the user when previous step is done. (No "proceed"-button exists.

The problem is: How do my template engine know which one to present? With or without proceed buttons? You can not just try to test a JS-block of code to determine if it is enabled before PHP loads the template.

One way I've worked out is the possibility that the initial load of the visit sends an ajax-request to a file on the server which only purpose is to set $_SESSION['JS_ENABLED'] = 1 or something like that.

I don't like this. The HTTP request for that file might very well fail leaving the site in belief that the visitor has JS disabled.

I think I need a new approach. Please enlighten me =)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have a multiple step registration form (like a wizard style interface), but why is JavaScript involved at this point? Can't you just have Page1 -- Page2 -- Page3 etc.. as normal separate forms? Each with a "Proceed"(submit) button? I must be missing some key piece of the puzzle here...

Comment: "I don't like this. The HTTP request for that file might very well fail leaving the site in belief that the visitor has JS disabled." True, it may fail, but no more so than any other page load might. If you are truly concerned about this possibility, you could try and perform the AJAX Call from each of the Non-Enhanced pages - if you have 4 pages, for instance, the likelihood of the AJAX Call failing (for a reason other than no javascript support) 4 out of 4 times is extremely low.

Comment: Lucanos: Yeah you are right about that. I thought about the fact that it wouldn't do much harm to make an ajax call on all page loads if the session variable isn't set to true. If JS is not enabled nothing will happen and no resources is wasted. Well. 200b in bandwitdh extra maybe. IE it will try to set the session variable to true until it succeed. If ever... :)

Comment: Java Dinker: Webb 2.0 you know :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do somethin like this:

```
<p>Step ....</p>
<a id="proceed_link" href="no_script_proceed_link.php">Proceed</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
// example with jquery
$.getScript('script/url.js',function(){ 
   $('#proceed_link').hide();
   // other stuff when scripts are available
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Without testing I assume that would actually display the link until the script actually runs and not hiding it until then?

Comment: well the idea is that you load the basic page and by getting a javascript file thru javascript, so you know javascript is enabled. without loading the script when there is no javascript support. and yes your assumption is correct